# How to convert IntPtr to int

Tags: c#, window-handles

A window handle sometimes of type `int` and other times of type `IntPtr`

`int` example:

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(int hWnd, int ProcessId);
```

`IntPtr` example:

```
  [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, StringBuilder lParam);
```

I don't seem to be able to convert/cast from one to the other.

When I try `this.ProcessID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(windowHandle.ToInt32(),0)` I get an error `cannot implicitly convert from uint to int`

Comment: `windowHandle.ToInt32()` will work.

Comment: @Henk holterman I edited the question, but still doesn't compile

Comment: You shouldn't edit away key parts of a question, add a next section.

Comment: Check your declaration of `this.ProcessID`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `SendMessage` signature is

```
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

or this

```
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, StringBuilder lParam);
```

Don't exchange `int` and `IntPtr`. They are nearly equivalent only at 32 bits (equal in size). At 64 bits an `IntPtr` is nearly equivalent to a `long` (equal in size)

The `GetWindowThreadProcessId` signature is

```
static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);
```

or

```
static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr ProcessId);
```

In this case, a `ref` or a `out` to "something" are managed references to something, so they are internally converted to `IntPtr` when passed to Native API. So `out uint` is, from the point of view of the Native API, equivalent to `IntPtr`.

Explanation: what is important is that the "length" of the parameters is the correct one. `int` and `uint` are equal for the called API. And a 32bit `IntPtr` is the same too.

Note that some types (like `bool` and `char`) have special handling by the marshaler.

You shouldn't EVER convert an `int` to an `IntPtr`. Keep it as an `IntPtr` and live happy. If you have to make some math operations not supported by `IntPtr`, use `long` (it's 64 bits, so until we will have *Windows 128*, there won't be any problem :-) ).

```
IntPtr p = ...
long l = (long)p;
p = (IntPtr)l;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that error `cannot implicitly convert from uint to int` refers to `=` statement. The field `this.ProcessID` is `int`, but `GetWindowThreadProcessId` returns `uint`.

Try this

```
this.ProcessID = unchecked((int)GetWindowThreadProcessId(windowHandle.ToInt32(),0))
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow", whenever I was:

```
IntPtr handler = OpenSCManager(null, null, SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE);
if (handler.ToInt32() == 0) //throws Exception
```

instead of that:

```
IntPtr handler = OpenSCManager(null, null, SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE);
if (handler == IntPtr.Zero) //OK
```