# Trouble raising events from C++ to be handled in C#

Tags: c#, events, c++-cli, eventhandler

I'm trying to write a C#-based WPF application that uses a C++ DLL. The C# application is for the user interface and it has all advantages of WPF. The C++ DLL uses Win32 functions (for example to enumerate windows).

Now I want the C++ DLL to raise event that can be handled in the C# application. This is what I've tried (based on [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073386/raise-events-in-c-cli-dll-and-consume-in-c-sharp)):

```
//cpp file

#using <System.dll>

using namespace System;

struct WIN {
    HWND Handle;
    char ClassName;
    char Title;
};

delegate void wDel(WIN);
event wDel^ wE;
void GotWindow(WIN Window) {
    wE(Window);
}
```

When I try to compile this code, these errors are thrown:

> C3708: 'wDel': improper use of 'event'; must be a member of a compatible event source
>
> C2059: syntax error: 'event'
>
> C3861: 'wE': identifier not found

Comment: The *event* keyword must appear inside a `public ref class`.  You furthermore must use managed `value struct` instead of a native `struct` to allow C# code to access the structure members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event needs to be a member of some managed class, possibly static. e.g.:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"

using namespace System;

struct WIN {
    HWND Handle;
    char ClassName;
    char Title;
};

delegate void wDel(WIN);

ref class WindowEvents abstract sealed // abstract sealed ref class in c++/cli is like a static class in c#
{
    public:
        static event wDel^ wE;

        static void GotWindow(WIN Window) {
            wE(Window);
        }
};
```

**Update**

If you need to [convert your unmanaged `HWND` to an `IntPtr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334261/convert-hwnd-to-intptr-cli), since [`IntPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the [standard P/Invoke signature for an HWND in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173211/how-to-convert-intptr-to-int), you might consider something like the following:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"

using namespace System;

#pragma managed(push,off)

struct WIN {  // Unmanaged c++ struct encapsulating the unmanaged data.
    HWND Handle;
    char ClassName;
    char Title;
};

#pragma managed(pop)

public value struct ManagedWIN  // Managed c++/CLI translation of the above.
{
public:
    IntPtr Handle; // Wrapper for an HWND
    char   ClassName;
    char   Title;
    ManagedWIN(const WIN win) : Handle(win.Handle), ClassName(win.ClassName), Title(win.Title)
    {
    }
};

public delegate void wDel(ManagedWIN);

public ref class WindowEvents abstract sealed // abstract sealed ref class in c++/cli is like a static class in c#
{
    public:
        static event wDel^ wE;

    internal:
        static void GotWindow(WIN Window) {
            wE(ManagedWIN(Window));
        }
};
```

Here `ManagedWIN` contains only safe .Net types.

Comment: use `value struct` instead of `struct`.

Comment: @Jan Böhm - answer updated with suggestion from ArthurCPPCLI.